# Why aren't angular animations working if I use them on a component

Tags: angular, animation

I have a list of Bootstrap pills displayed using an `*ngFor`. I have applied an animation on the pills so that they slide-in when added, and fade-out when removed. All works fine.

However, if I extract the markup of a pill into an Angular component and apply the animation on the component, then only the fade-out animation works, but not the slide-in.

On the contrary, if I apply the animation to the root `span` element inside the pill component, then I have the inverse problem: the slide-in works fine, but the fade-out doesn't.

Why doesn't it work the same way in all three cases? And how to make both animations work in all three cases?

I guess the third case doesn't work because the parent of the animated element is removed from the DOM, and not just the animated element itself. But I don't understand why the second case does not work.

Here's [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8wzj1m-yftkdj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) showing everything in action.

Here's the relevant code of the three cases.

### First case: everything works:

#### app.component.html

```
<span
  *ngFor="let pill of pills"
  @fadeInAndOut
  class="badge badge-pill badge-primary mr-1 mb-1"
  >{{ pill.value }}
</span>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root', 
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInAndOut', [
      transition(':enter', [style({ width: '0' }), animate('.5s ease-out', style({ width: '*' }))]),
      transition(':leave', [animate('.5s ease-out', style({ opacity: '0' }))])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  pills = [];

  addPill() {
    this.pills.push({ value: 'hello' });
  }

  removePill() {
    if (this.pills.length) {
      this.pills.splice(this.pills.length - 1, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

### Second case: only fade-out works

#### app.component.html

```
<app-pill
  *ngFor="let pill of pills"
  @fadeInAndOut
>{{ pill.value }}</app-pill>
```

#### pill.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pill', 
  templateUrl: './pill.component.html',
  styles: [':host { display: inline-block; }']
})
export class PillComponent {
}
```

#### pill.component.html

```
<span
  class="badge badge-pill badge-primary mr-1 mb-1"
  ><ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
```

### Third case: only slide-in works

#### app.component.html

```
<app-animated-pill
    *ngFor="let pill of pills"
  >{{ pill.value }}</app-animated-pill>
```

#### animated-pill.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-animated-pill', 
  templateUrl: './animated-pill.component.html',
  styles: [':host { display: inline-block; }'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInAndOut', [
      transition(':enter', [style({ width: '0' }), animate('.5s ease-out', style({ width: '*' }))]),
      transition(':leave', [animate('.5s ease-out', style({ opacity: '0' }))])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AnimatedPillComponent {
}
```

#### animated-pill.component.html

```
<span
  @fadeInAndOut
  class="badge badge-pill badge-primary mr-1 mb-1"
  ><ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
```

Comment: Are you trying to perform a *nested* animation?

Comment: No. Just to animate the pill component.